# Visual Studio cannot resolve model, but Razor pages loads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I have an MVC 5 application, made from the empty template.  I've added `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` via Nuget and my packages file looks like so:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

I have a Razor page that declares a model with `@model IEnumerable<Models.ToDoModel>` and uses it in a foreach loop.

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.ToDoModel>

<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li>ID: @item.Id</li>
        }
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the page, it renders fine, however Visual Studio persistently said there's an error:

[image: cannot resolve symbol 'model']

It won't recognise the `model` keyword or give me any Intellisense.

My `Web.Config` looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and the `Web.Config` in the `Views` folder looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You've tried closing and reopening VS?

Comment: @DavidG I had, however, I had other instances of Visual Studio open.  Closing them *all* worked!

Comment: In that case, problem solved!!

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Would you like to stick it below as the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your web.configs both look fine. Visual Studio can often get confused about things like this. My recommendation is to close Visual Studio and reopen it. Also, as you discovered, closing *all* open instances of VS may be required.

Comment: Interesting issue.  Vs "confused". Nothing in here solved it for me.  Nothing i do recongizes Model or model in my foreach.  I've also noticed @script tags not working either.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for either. I removed all my extensions, reinstalled VS, but still sam error

Answer (score 21):

If you have resharper , suspending it will fix i.e: `Tool - Options - Resharper - Suspend`

[image: Options Menu Screenshot]

Answer (score 11):

Closing ALL instances of Visual Studio worked for you, great.

I get this symptom periodically, but I am using Resharper, and to fix it I have to

- go into Resharper-Options "Clear Caches",
- and then close and reopen
  Visual Studio

Comment: You don't need to bounce Visual Studio, you can just go to Options/Resharper and hit the Suspend button, then Resume.  Same effect.

Comment: I followed your tip and @model and Model makes sense in cshtml files again. Resharper should try to fix this central issue.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue and tried every solution under the sun. For a week I tried editing the web config (in both the view and the root), reloading the project, clearing resharper caches.. you name it, I tried it. 
I loaded up an old project and hovered over the "Layout" and "Model" sections to see what namespaces they required. On closer examination, the namespaces which were required had been removed from my project. I have no idea how - I had recently performed an upgrade.. Anyhow - I referenced these 2 files from the solution folder System.Web.Mvc and another, rebuilt, and it worked. I could have danced on the spot. Hope this helps someone down the line!