# Cannot resolve Symbol "Session" in the _Layout view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, view

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 5 App.

I try to access to a session variable in the _layout.cshtml view.

The code is the following one :

```
@{ var user = Session["idUser"];}
```

The problem is that the error is

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Session'

When I define the session variable in my controller it works.

```
Session["idUser"] = idUser;
```

Can I access to the Session variable in the view ? If not why ?

Comment: That looks correct. Sometimes VS gets confused. Try running it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130521/visual-studio-cannot-resolve-model-but-razor-pages-loads)

Comment: Yes, it is correct and it works perfectly fine. Thanks.