# Visual Studio 2019 Razor Syntax Highlighting When Using Local Functions

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

The VS2019 syntax highlighting seems to be going berzerk when confronted with a local function in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor view. A function like this:

```
@{
  void Buttons()
  {
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <button type="submit" name="Command" value="close">Save & Close</button>
          <button type="submit" name="Command" value="save">Save & Stay</button>
          <button type="submit" name="Command" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>
  }
}
```

shows up highlighted as full of errors, when in fact it compiles and works just fine. Hovering the mouse pointer over the `<div>` pops up `Cannot resolve symbol <div>.` message.

Has anybody found a workaround, or do we need to wait for VS highlighting to catch up with the new syntax?

Comment: Suggestions in this post could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130521/visual-studio-cannot-resolve-model-but-razor-pages-loads

Comment: @as.if.i.code Indeed! It turns out to be a ReSharper issue. Suspending ReSharper clears the error. Even the latest update (2019.3.3) does not solve it, though.

Comment: [JetBrains: Add support for markup in local functions and @functions in Razor views](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-34875)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is "there is no answer."

There is a JetBrains issue for this problem at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-34875